# How to convert all dates from UTC to Local time using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have very complex structure that I receive from server-side code.
This structure has many Date properties (of type Date).
These Date properties contain dates in UTC.
I need to convert all of them to Local.
Is there any way to do this in angularJS?
Instead of doing this one-by-one?
Maybe some global setting or options that will instruct angular to convert dates into Local automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a "UTC" time zone you can pass to [the date filter AngularJS provides](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: tried that, it doesnt change TimeZone, only a format. Say, I get UTC date "2016-10-20 10:00 AM", after using filter with 'UTC' parameter, I DONT get "2016-10-20 15:00", if I am in Canada (-5 hours)

Comment: Have you tried [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

append " UTC" to the backend time and run that through new Date().  It'll give you the local time offset.

```js
var backEndDate = "2016-10-20 10:00 AM" + " UTC";
console.log(new Date(backEndDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is change your web service to return the utc date using ISO 8601 format.
For example: "2016-10-07T22:01:00Z"

If the web service return's the date using this ISO is easy to represents the date in local time of user because the browser instances the date based on your current time zone.
For example: if i open my browser console and run this javascript code:

```
new Date("2016-10-07T22:01:00Z")
```

I will receive the date based on my time zone, that is GMT-0300.

```
Fri Oct 07 2016 19:01:00 GMT-0300 (SA Eastern Standard Time)
```

So, for angularjs code you just need write::

```
{{"2016-10-07T22:01:00Z" | date}}
```

i will receive this result:

```
Oct 7, 2016
```

Check the filter for date [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)
For use the filter correctly. For example:

```
{{"2016-10-07T22:01:00Z" | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm'}}
```

The result is:`10/07/2016 19:01`

The second approach is convert the date from your web service for the ISO 8601 format.
Actually i had the same problem and the client web service sends me the date just like this: `"2016-10-07 22:01:00"`

So, i wrote a simple code to convert this date format to ISO 8601.